# filter in levels and fetch a value

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, lubridate

I have a bit of a complicated situation,
I'm running a clinic and I need your guy's help with something:

I have a column which is a factor type "c_code" and it has many levels with different lengths.
In each row, I have a column "session" which indicates the session number of a client.
I'm trying to fetch only the highest session of each c_code level and check if it has been over a week since this clent came to therapy.
This is the DF that I'm using:
[image: My Data Frame]

As you can see, I'm trying to use this row:

```
mutate(bigThan6= if_else(as.double(todayDate - date) > 6, 1, 0))
```

so that "bigThan6" column get 1 if the different is above 6.

My problem if that I dont want it to be done over my entire row -
only those which are highlighted in the picture: the **highest session in each "c_code" level**

Comment: Is `c_code` the client identifier?

Comment: It would be much easier to help if you provided data that is copy/pasteable rather than a picture. (Can't test code on a picture of data!) Could you share `dput(droplevels(your_data[1:10, ]))` for the first 10 rows, or share a different illustrative subset of data? This will by copy/pasteable for us and include all relevant class and structure information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do as follows.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(c_code) %>%
  mutate(bigThan6 = +(session == max(session) &
                      toDate - date > 6))

#   c_code session date       toDate     bigThan6
#   <chr>    <dbl> <date>     <date>        <int>
# 1 a            1 2020-01-01 2020-11-09        0
# 2 a            2 2020-01-10 2020-11-09        1
# 3 b            2 2020-01-20 2020-11-09        0
# 4 b            3 2020-01-23 2020-11-09        1
# 5 c            3 2020-11-07 2020-11-09        0
# 6 c            4 2020-11-08 2020-11-09        0
```

Arbitrary demo date

````
df <- structure(list(c_code = c("a", "a", "b", "b", "c", "c"), session = c(1, 
2, 2, 3, 3, 4), date = structure(c(18262, 18271, 18281, 18284, 
18573, 18574), class = "Date"), toDate = structure(c(18575, 18575, 
18575, 18575, 18575, 18575), class = "Date")), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))```
````

Comment: Thank you, it worked. I understood how you grouped by c_code can can you please explain to me how does the +(session == max(session) worked? what is the + for? thanks again!

Comment: @Ido: You are very welcome. ```session == max(session)``` returns ```TRUE``` for the highest value(s) within session and ```FALSE``` otherwise. The ```+``` operator converts the lgl-vector into a int-vector containing zeros and ones.

Answer (score 0):

Untested as you haven't shared your data, but I think this is what you want:

```
your_data %>%
  group_by(c_code) %>%
  mutate(
    big_than_6 = case_when(
      date < max(date) ~ NA_integer_,
      datediff(todayDate, date, "days") > 6 ~ 1L,
      TRUE ~ 0L 
  ))
```